# The OpsMgr Health Service service terminated with service-specific error 2148073487 (0x8009000F)

Tags: scom

I'm using Microsoft System Center Operations Manager 2007 SP1 and I'm having some problems getting the client installed on a couple of servers. They are Windows 2008 (not R2) SP1. (I'm going to try updating it to SP2 to see if that fixes it)

The error that I get is:

```
The OpsMgr Health Service service terminated with service-specific error 2148073487 (0x8009000F).
```

That's the only detail that appears in the event log. The service fails to install if I deploy it through the management console, and if I install it manually it says that it failed to start.

I'm not sure what other information I can give to be of help in diagnosing this as I'm fairly new to it, but there's very little information out there on the web so if I fix the problem then I'll post an answer here!

Thanks

Comment: Please see the service specific "Operations Manager" log in event viewer, it proabably contains some events just prior to the termination

Comment: I hadn't thought of that at the time. Unfortunately I no longer work for that company although I know where to look if I find it again! Thanks